# Buttons color change after getting the value of hidden field

Tags: javascript, java, css, html, jsp

I have buttons arround 170 on my page. and if button clicked then color changed and also i stored the id of that button in java string array for update in database.i can use hidden field for accessing button id. if i  get button id then page will refresh then button of color changed. so please give me a solution for this problem please help me

```
enter code here

   <script>     

        <%int index = 0;%>

        //FUNCTION CALL IF BUTTONS CLICKED
        function sub(id) {
            if (ss < pp) {
                if (document.getElementById(id).style.background == "") {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.background = "#ff0000";
                    ss++;
                    //HIDDEN IS THE ID OF HIDDEN TAG...
                    var val = document.getElementById("hidden");
                    val.value = id;
                    //THIS IS MY JAVA CODE.. IN THIS I SHALL CONNECT TO DATABASE AND ENTRY IN DB USING UPDATE VARIABLE
        <%

         String[] update = new String[100];
         if (request.getParameter("hidden") != null) {
             update[index] = request.getParameter("hidden");

         }
        %>
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.background = "";
                    ss--;

                }
                if (ss == pp) {
                    if (document.getElementById(id).style.background == "") {
                        alert("exceed!!");
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "";
                        ss--;

                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: please give me a solution

Comment: You are mixing front-end (Javascript) and back-end (JSP) functionality. When your Javascript is executed in browser, the page has already been generated with JSP on server, and JSP has no access to your javascript values. You have to use AJAX to pass the values from browser to server. Start e.g. with https://blog.udemy.com/jsp-ajax/